# whitespace trimmer plugin remove only white color

Tags: c#, imageresizer

I am using Imageresizer creative version

I am able to implement whitespace trimmer plugin of imageresizer ,but problem is its removing all colors, how can we say

that only to remove white color,

Example

[Original Image](https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa.SentientPrime.media/44f0feb379d8ced4368137740897f8cf/primes/1/Prime1Copy.png)

[Trimmed Image](https://s3.amazonaws.com/qa.SentientPrime.media/03203fc0adc995d8c470c5a56af0270b/targets/4/Prime1_461x169.png?r=0.176300610533903)

you can see its removing back ground colors as well

code is very simple

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(bmpStream, stream, new Instructions("trim.threshold=80&trim.percentpadding=0.5")));
```

How can we say to remove only white spaces

Thanks

Comment: Downvoter , please don't feel shame to put some comment as well,

Answer (score 0):

WhitespaceTrimmer uses an energy filter to detect 'background color'. It can, for example, trim away a background gradient. It can't be tuned to only remove a specific color, although you could adjust the source code to do so.

The [documentation covers how you can adjust the threshold value](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/whitespacetrimmer), which should give you the control you want without sacrificing a general-purpose solution. I assure you that tying whitespace trimming to specific colors is not a great idea.